# SQL Server : datetime incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008,

I have a procedure as follows:

```
SELECT 
    UserId, Name, Company, LanguageId, CodeRegisteredWith, TotalLoggedInDuration, 
    Region, IsAdmin,
    IsRep, IsRetailer, IsTeamLeader, [dateregistered] 
FROM 
    RoundupAcademy.dbo.UserProfile WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE 
    (Convert(smalldatetime, DateRegistered, 120) >= Convert(smalldatetime, '2013-1-1', 120) 
    AND (Convert(smalldatetime, DateRegistered, 120) <= convert(smalldatetime, '2013-8-8', 120)))
```

This works fine and shows the results between the dates.

However when expanding on this query and some more conditions as follows:

```
SELECT 
   UserId, Name, Company, LanguageId, CodeRegisteredWith, TotalLoggedInDuration,     
   Region, IsAdmin, IsRep, IsRetailer, IsTeamLeader, [dateregistered] 
FROM 
   RoundupAcademy.dbo.UserProfile WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE 
   UserId is not null OR UserId not like '' 
   AND 
   (@LanguageID = 0 OR ([LanguageID] = @LanguageID ))
   AND 
   ((Convert(smalldatetime, DateRegistered, 120) >= Convert(smalldatetime, @datereg,  120) 
AND (Convert(smalldatetime, DateRegistered, 120) <= convert(smalldatetime, @dateend, 120))))
```

it seems any date shows.

not sure what the problem is as my other conditions look fine.

any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is the line `WHERE UserID is not null OR UserID not like ''`. You should put those statements in parantheses.

Comment: could it be so simple? so simple i missed parentheses where an OR condition is?  .....yes......*facepalm* completely overlooked the OR!
thanks for that!

Comment: You should always split `ORs` and `ANDs` with parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
WHERE UserId is not null OR UserId not like ''
```

with

```
WHERE (UserId is not null OR UserId not like '')
```

Otherwise you would get all records where `UserId is not null` **or** the other conditions are true.

Answer (score 1):

query should be like these

```
SELECT UserId, Name, Company, LanguageId, CodeRegisteredWith, TotalLoggedInDuration, Region, IsAdmin,
IsRep, IsRetailer, IsTeamLeader, [dateregistered] FROM RoundupAcademy.dbo.UserProfile WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE( UserId is not null OR UserId not like '') 
AND 
(@LanguageID = 0 OR ([LanguageID] = @LanguageID ))
AND 
((Convert(smalldatetime,DateRegistered, 120) >= Convert(smalldatetime,@datereg,  120) 
AND (Convert(smalldatetime,DateRegistered, 120) <= convert(smalldatetime,@dateend, 120))))
```